# Is there a way in Python how to use value rather than type, as generic parameter?

Tags: python, generics, typing

I'm making my Discord snowflakes implementation. There was a need to use different eras for Snowflake parser/generator. How I can do that?

I want something like:

```py
DiscordSnowflake = Snowflake[DISCORD_EPOCH]
MySnowflake = Snowflake[MY_EPOCH]
```

Answer (score 0):

python type hint may help. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

here is a example

```
Vector = list[float]
def scale(scalar: float, vector: Vector) -> Vector:
    return [scalar * num for num in vector]

# passes type checking; a list of floats qualifies as a Vector.
new_vector = scale(2.0, [1.0, -4.2, 5.4])
```

Comment: I know, but that are type aliases. I want use generic parameter as epoch constant in the Snowflake class.